# Can't update or install anything kubuntu 14.10

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, kubuntu, 14.10

it started out with wanting to install gimp, but I think I have bigger problems.  I can't seem to update or upgrade my current system.  I’m running kubuntu 14.10.  when I do `sudo apt-get update` I get this:

```
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security InRelease
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                                      
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic InRelease                                               
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security Release.gpg                                      
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates InRelease                                       
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                          
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security Release               
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports InRelease          
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                              
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex            
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-proposed InRelease                                  
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease                        
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic Release.gpg                  
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates Release.gpg          
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports Release.gpg        
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-proposed Release.gpg         
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease                        
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic Release                      
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates Release              
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                  
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports Release                                                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release.gpg                                            
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-proposed Release             
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                   
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex                                 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release.gpg                      
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release                          
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex                        
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex                 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release                          
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                                      
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main amd64 Packages              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en                             
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex         
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages                              
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en               
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-proposed/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-proposed/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-proposed/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-proposed/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-proposed/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-proposed/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-proposed/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe Translation-en
Err http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-en_US                                                     
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-proposed/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-proposed/main Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-proposed/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-proposed/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-proposed/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-proposed/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-proposed/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-proposed/universe Translation-en
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-proposed/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-proposed/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-proposed/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-proposed/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-proposed/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-proposed/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-proposed/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-proposed/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-proposed/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-proposed/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-proposed/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-proposed/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-proposed/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-proposed/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-proposed/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

and when i try to use `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` i get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

i'm really not sure what's going on here, or how to solve it.  please help.

Comment: what does sudo ifconfig say? this reeks of a network connectivity problem.